# Apache2 web page filtered by iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, apache2

Situation: I have an Ubuntu 18.04 box configured as a router and a firewall (iptables) with two legs, and an Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache2 (for compatibility reasons).

Problem: Below are the two lines of rules giving me a headache:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.5.0/24 -d 10.1.2.10/32 -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.2.10/32 -d 10.1.5.0/24 -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

When the iptables rules are flushed, I can access the web server normally, however, just applying a simple rule like below:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.5.0/24 -d 10.1.2.10/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.2.10/32 -d 10.1.5.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

causes my web server to stop responding. Tcpdump suggests that the web server was contacted, and the TCP handshake is potentially done, just that the web server did not reply with the webpage.

10.1.2.10 is my web server, while 10.1.5.0/24 is a subnet with 'user' machines.

Question: Is there something wrong with my iptables? Or potentially an Apache misconfiguration?

Update: The following rules got the web server replying properly (I still don't get why). If I try to apply even any other filters such as limiting by ports, destination, or `ctstate`, the web server stops forwarding. The `tcpdump` output suggests the same problem as before -- TCP Handshake potentially completed, just no webpages forwarded.

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.2.10/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.5.0/24 -d 10.1.2.10/32 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your simple rules.  Rather than this:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.5.0/24 -d 10.1.2.10/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.1.2.10/32 -s 10.1.5.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

They should read:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.5.0/24 -d 10.1.2.10/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.1.2.10/32 -d 10.1.5.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Your first attempt produced two identical rules, the 2nd of which would never be hit.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo when I posted the question. Corrected

Comment: If that didn't solve your problem, and the TCP handshake is completing correctly, you might be experiencing an MTU mismatch. If you post your complete `iptables` ruleset (preferably the minimal ruleset necessary to see the problem) and a link to your `tcpdump` output, we might be able to work out more.